# How to stop gdb stepping through intrinsic functions in Fortran code?

Tags: gdb, centos, fortran

I'm debugging some Fortran code with gdb and it keeps stepping through the C code for intrinsic Fortran functions. For example if I try to step past a `write` call, it jumps into `write.c`. Is there any way to stop this behaviour? I'm on CentOS 6.3, with gdb 7.2 and gfortran 4.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I think "next" should work.  But I don't know Fortran, maybe something funny is going on.

Another way is to ensure that you don't have debug info for the intrinsics installed.  gdb will automatically skip over functions that don't have debuginfo if you try to "step" into them.

The final way is to upgrade your gdb and use the new "skip" command, which was added exactly for this use case.

Comment: I should've said that I'd tried both "step" and "next". I think I may have to resort to just uninstalling gcc-debuginfo and hope nothing breaks. The latest version of gdb is not available in the CentOS repos, so I would have to install it myself.

Comment: If you find yourself in an odd function, you can "finish" out of it.  Also, please be sure to file a GCC bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this where next wasn't working when I was remote debugging on a cross-compiled target. I finally realized that I had loaded the wrong executable/symbol table using gdb's file command. Hitting next was jumping in to places un-releated to the current line of code. It was doing the best it could given the information I gave it :)